# Disruptor onEvent handler

Tags: disruptor-pattern

In various examples of an onEvent sometimes the variables are declared as final and sometimes not.

For example:

```
public void onEvent(final ValueEvent entry, final long sequence, final boolean onEndOfBatch)
```

opposed to

```
public void onEvent(ValueEvent entry, long sequence, boolean onEndOfBatch)
```

Please can I get a comment on the reason and use of final?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is the LMAX coding standards call for parameters to be `final`, however that is just a matter of convention.

Adding final to the parameter just means that the method cannot change the value of the primitives or re-assign the references for the objects passed through. See here for further details [on final](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.nz/2011/12/final-variable-method-class-java.html)

Many people consider assigning a new value to a parameter to be bad practice and lead to many subtle bugs.